# Does AngularJS have a native deferred $rootScope.$apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a lot of code that looks like this:

```
obj.bind( 'event', function(){
    $rootScope.$apply( function(){
        somePromise.resolve();
        doSomething();
    }
} );
```

I'd like to compress it to something akin to:

```
obj.bind( 'event', deferRootScopeApply( function(){
    somePromise.resolve();
    doSomething();
} );
```

It's easy enough to write a service that does this, but I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner native way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, this is my service:

```
app.factory( 'rootApply', [ '$rootScope', function( $rootScope ){
    return function( fn, scope ){
        var args = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        // push null as scope if necessary
        args.length || args.push( null );

        return function(){
            // binds to the scope and any arguments
            var callFn = fn.bind.apply(
                  fn
                , args.slice().concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) )
            );

            // prevent applying/digesting twice
            $rootScope.$$phase
                ? callFn()
                : $rootScope.$apply( callFn )
                ;
        }
    };
} ] );
```

which then returns a deferred function or optionally acts like `fn.call`:

```
rootApply( someFunction );
rootApply( someFunction, scope, arg1, arg2, arg3 );
```